# How to change LLVM version on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: ubuntu, llvm, ubuntu-15.10

I currently have `LLVM 3.6.2` installed on Ubuntu 15.10. But I would like to use `LLVM 3.7`. I have tried following the steps on http://llvm.org/apt/ but even though the installation was successful, the version is still the same.

Is there any way to change the current LLVM version that is in use?

Also, another thing to note is that `LLVM 3.7-dev` is not installable

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 llvm-3.7-dev : Depends: libjsoncpp0 (>= 0.6.0~rc2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Any suggestions?

Comment: On my Ubuntu 15.10 llvm-3.7-dev is in the default repositories and installed just fine.

Comment: You may need to use `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade`.  Take a serious look at the man page to decide which you may wish to use [if any].  You could also pull the source for 3.7  independently of `apt-get` and build it from scratch.  You could then install it as /usr/local/private/llvm or some such so as to not conflict with/disturb the standard version.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "even though the installation was successful"? you'd better provide more details during your installation.

Comment: @HongxuChen I mean that it was fully downloaded and installed and there were no errors during the installation.

Comment: @CraigEstey How exactly do i install it and then set it as private so that it doesn't conflict with the standard version currently in use (3.6.2)? Total beginner so I don't fully know how to change these things on Ubuntu.

Comment: @user3588132 Actually I suspect you have problems installing these packages. To ensure you have really "installed" these packages, you might need to try "dpkg -L clang-3.7" (and other `package` names) and there should be information about the "installed" paths for these packages. After you have confirmed that all the packages are correctly installed, try something like "which -a clang" (or "clang-3.7", other `executables`' names ditto, specially "llvm-config"). If that displays correctly (e.g., `3.7` in the first executable's path), you might need to have a check "llvm-config --version".

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the other versions and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a page on how to install multiple package versions from apt: https://serverfault.com/questions/279329/can-i-have-two-versions-of-the-same-package-in-an-apt-repository

But, to build from source, most of the files and info is on http://clang.llvm.org

Here's the download page: http://llvm.org/releases/download.html  From there, you can download source tarballs.

Also, there is a prebuilt tarball for clang+llvm for ubuntu 14.04 [will probably work for 15.10].  Chances are good that you can extract it to /usr/local/clang_whatever and with some makefile changes, you can get your make to use it.  The prebuilt is: http://llvm.org/releases/3.7.0/clang+llvm-3.7.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-14.04.tar.xz

To rebuild from source, go to the developer page [don't let the word developer scare you], and follow instructions.  That's here: http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html You're rebuilding as a clang developer would, you just don't start hacking the clang source.  `svn` is pretty automatic.  Yes, you're hooking up to a source code control repository [not to be confused with a "distro" repository like debian or ubuntu], but that's fine.  Once you get it compiled, you needn't update via svn if you don't want to.

Or, if `svn` isn't your cup of tea, from the download page, download the necessary source tarballs

Either way:

To specify an alternate install point, you use `cmake`'s `--target` option.  See here for the howto: http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html  This is also an alternate page for full instructions on source build of clang/llvm, assuming you've got extracted sources

Actually, now that I think about it, rebuilding from source (either svn or tarballs) is probably surer/safer than the prebuilt tarball approach

Comment: I think the PO only meant to use a pre-built package from llvm's nightly repo.

Comment: @HongxuChen OP asked me how to do it to a _different_ install location [as I suggested].  Gave him link to keep multiple ubuntu versions, main page, download page, a prebuilt 3.7.0 tarball [AFAICT, they don't do packages], two ways to download source, two links to how to build from source.  Prebuilt might work [I extracted it to examine], but didn't see if it would install [easily] in an alt place [at OP's skill level].  In my experience, when needing an alt version with alt install point, source rebuild is usually the best way [and surprisingly, easier in the end]